# Configure SonarLint Analyzers properties

Tags: c#, sonarlint

I've added the SonarLint C# Roslyn analyzer to a project (via the [SonarAnalyzer for C#](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SonarAnalyzer.CSharp/) NuGet package) in Visual Studio. Is it possible to configure how the analyzer rules operate?

For example, the [CodeComplexity analyser appears to have a Threshold property](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-dotnet/blob/master/analyzers/src/SonarAnalyzer.CSharp/Rules/CognitiveComplexity.cs#L41) to which I'd like to set a different value.

I've found a couple of references to a SonarLint.xml file, but creating such a file and locating it at the solution level doesn't seem to have had any effect.

Here's the content of the SonarLint.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AnalysisInput>
  <Rules>
    <Rule>
      <Key>S3776</Key>
      <Parameters>
        <Parameter>
          <Key>threshold</Key>
          <Value>30</Value>           
        </Parameter>
      </Parameters>
    </Rule>
  </Rules>
  <Files>
  </Files>
</AnalysisInput>
```

Answer (score 2):

Include the SonarLint.xml file in the project and set the `Build Action` file property to `AdditionalFiles`.

Diving in to the SonarLint source code led me to [this class](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/blob/master/sonaranalyzer-dotnet/src/SonarAnalyzer.Common/Helpers/ParameterLoadingDiagnosticAnalyzer.cs), which makes use of the [`AnalyzerOptions` class](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Compilers/Core/Portable/DiagnosticAnalyzer/AnalyzerOptions.cs). This then led me to the documentation in the Roslyn repository about [Additional Files](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/analyzers/Using%20Additional%20Files.md).