# How to configure SonarAnalyzer.CSharp S1451 Track lack of copyright and license headers when using .editorconfig

Tags: sonarqube, roslyn-code-analysis, static-code-analysis, editorconfig

I am not using SonarQube local server, or SonarCloud, or SonarLint. I instead just reference the SonarAnalyzer.CSharp nuget package directly in each of my .NET Core projects and configure the rule severity using .editorconfig ([more info](https://aaron-hoffman.blogspot.com/2020/09/configure-sonaranalyzercsharp-with-editorconfig.html))

How can I configure the license header format with this setup? By just setting the severity to 'error', the analyzer expects to see the default SQ license header.

Answer (score 1):

SonarAnalyzer.CSharp doesn't currently support setting custom rule parameters in the `.editorconfig` file.

You need to create a separate `SonarLint.xml` file in the correct format and reference it as an `AdditionalFile`.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42989826/configure-sonarlint-analyzers-properties) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Check [StyleCopAnalyzers](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1633.md) for adding copyright and license headers when using .editorconfig

dotnet_diagnostic.SA1633.severity=warning